# Least number of cuboids required to form a cube

Tags: geometry, contest-math, puzzle

What is the least number of identical cuboids, each of dimension $2cm*4cm*5cm$, that are required to form a cube?

My approach: Since the final cube will have dimensions of form $a^3$ so we only need 25 cuboids so to get a cube with side, $a=2*5$.

But the answer to this question is $200$. Here, $a=20=LCM(2,4,5)$ is assumed and then answewr is obtained by dividing the volume of cube by that of cuboid.

Could you please point out the mistake in my approach and why the other one works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although $25$ such pieces have the same volume as a $10\times10\times10$ cube, they cannot fill such a cube.

**Proof:**

Think of the $10\times10\times10$ as a $5\times5\times5$ cube built of $125$ $2\times2\times2$ blocks. If you were to colour that cube like a checkerboard, there will be $63$ blocks of one colour and $62$ of the other.
However you place a $2\times4\times5$ piece, it will fill an equal number of unit cubes of each colour. To understand this, it suffices to consider smaller $2\times4\times1$ pieces. The illustration below shows that such a piece always covers $4$ of each colour. So using $125$ of them still covers the same amount of each colour and therefore cannot fill the cube which has unequal amounts. Since $2\times4\times5$ pieces can be split into five $2\times4\times1$ pieces, any $2\times4\times5$ piece also covers the same amount of each colour and cannot be used to fill the cube.

[image]

The smallest number that is a cube larger $10^3$ but divisible by $2\cdot4\cdot5=40$ (the volume of a piece), is $20^3$ because obviously none of $11^3$ to $19^3$ are even divisible by $10$.

Comment: I'm unable to get why it won't be able to fill.

Comment: @InanimateBeing Are you familiar with colouring proofs? Look at for example [the mutilated chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem). The proof here is essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link, now I get the colouring proof. "Think of the 10×10×10 as a 5×5×5 cube built of 125 2×2×2 blocks." This line means 125 2x2x2 cubes isn't it? And " 2×4×5 piece, it will fill and equal number of unit cubes of each colour", how? I'm unable to picturize it due to the dimension 5 of the cuboid.

Comment: Imagine a 2x4x1 block instead. This 2x4 will always cover 4 of each colour. Therefore so will the 2x4x5.

Comment: Now I'm lost. Sorry, but could you please explain the answer a bit more so a rookie like me can get it. I find the language quite confusing to me, like 5x5x5 "cube" or "filling equal number of unit cubes". I can understand that many of these things might be obvious for an average person but I'm not average, sigh.

Comment: @InanimateBeing I have added a picture.

Comment: I now get almost all of it but for 2 doubts. 1. Why we aren't concerned with the dimension 5 of the cube? 2. Why we looking for another cube that also divides 10^3?

Comment: I upvoted anyways as I learnt a lot

Comment: If a 2x4x1 block covers the same amount of each colour, then five of them side by side will also fill the same amount of each colour. Strictly speaking, we are looking for the next cube divisible by 40, the volume of our pieces, so I made an edit.